# How to implement shutdown hook handler in google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How to implement shutdown hook handler in google appengine . Im not understanding their doc here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#Shutdown. what i need is, i  need to be notified in the code when backend is stopped due to any to reason.

```
this is my code
try{        
    while (haveMoreWork() &&
        !LifecycleManager.getInstance().isShuttingDown()) {
            process(); // this is my function to read all the data.if it fails because of termination.i need to be notified.
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        log.severe("error occured"+e);
        log.info("failed ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the hook instead of the status report:

```
LifecycleManager.getInstance().setShutdownHook(new ShutdownHook() {
  public void shutdown() {
    // code
  }
});
```